# How to specify an example for an object type in api-blueprint

Tags: apiblueprint

Is it possible to specify an example value for 'bar' in type Baz in the following data structure?

```
# Data Structures
## Foo (object)
   + arg0 (number, required) - the arg0
   + arg1 (number, optional) - the arg1
   + arg2: a, b, c (enum, required) - the arg2

## Baz (object)
  + bar (Foo, required)
```

Thanks in advance

--Ulrich

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to provide an example by specifying each property of the complex object, something like this:

```
+ bar (Foo, required)
    + Sample
        + (object)
            + arg0: 1
            + arg1: 2
```